# How long should one wait before accepting an answer?

Tags: discussion

A question is posted and after two or three weeks, five or six answers are come under it. Should the user wait for more answers or this time is enough for the question to be answered and he has to choose one and put check mark beside it?

How much should the user wait for his question to be answered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [StackExchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work):

> - Don't hesitate to accept an answer that is well-written, suggests a good practice and works for you.
> - Otherwise, even if there are answers that are good enough but that you're not entirely satisfied by, you might wait 24 to 48 hours to give other people a chance to give you a better answer. A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer.

So, the SE recommendation is: if you're completely satisfied with an answer, accept it immediately. If you're mostly satisfied with an answer, accept it within a couple of days.

(Note that you can change your accepted answer if a better one comes along later.)

This is only a recommendation; you can accept an answer immediately, years later, not at all, etc. if that's what you want to do.

Comment: +1 for "you can change your accepted answer".